# How to send xml to an IP and get xml response in android?

Tags: java, android, sockets, stream, inputstream

I am trying to send xml to an IP. I am doing that with following code:

```
String sMessage = "<SERVER><CONNECT><IP>192.168.10.14</IP><CLIENT_ID>123</CLIENT_ID></CONNECT></SERVER>";
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.252.148", 34543);
System.out.println("socket connected---: "+socket.isConnected());
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
out.println(sMessage);
byte[] buffer = new byte[in.available()];
in.read(buffer);
String rMsg = new String(buffer);
System.out.println("rMsg: "+rMsg);
out.close();
in.close();
socket.close();
```

rMsg is always empty. socket connection is true. Why am i not getting response back. I tried to change InputStream to BufferedInputStream but it did not help. Any idea to solve this problem by either fixing this code or by having new idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Your sending an XML file to an address, fair enough, but why are you automatically assuming the destination knows how to understand and create an XML formatted reply? What is the server-side implementation?

If there is such an implementation and you are not receiving data, then there must be a problem on that end, could you post code from it?

Answer (score 0):

What should the server send you back? The thing is that you send an XML to the server and want to receive input at the same time from the server. But the response from the server may take some time. But I guess at this point your inputstream is closed or you are not listening to that any more. One simple solution to check that will be to put everythin in a while loop so you will see if your server answers (a bit later)... you also can listen to the NIC of your server with wireshark. Perhaps your server doesn't send anything?